# Open files or folders containing a space from Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, filenames

When I try to open a folder or file that has a space in its name, it returns an error.

For example, when trying to open `Java Scripts.txt`:

```
PS C:\Users\Sergio\Desktop> cat Java Scripts.txt
Get-Content : No se encuentra ningún parámetro de posición que acepte el argumento 'Scripts.txt'.
En línea: 1 Carácter: 1
+ cat Java Scripts.txt
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-Content], ParameterBindingException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand
```

Retaining the file's original name as much as possible, is there a way to use some special characters to replace the space or do I have to change the file/folder name?

Answer (score 1):

```
cat "Java Scripts.txt"
```

or

```
cat 'Java Scripts.txt'
```

Read

- [about_Quoting_Rules](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847740.aspx) and
- [Single Quotes vs. Double Quotes in PowerShell: What's the Difference?](http://windowsitpro.com/blog/single-quotes-vs-double-quotes-powershell-whats-difference) and
- … (Google for *powershell double and single quotes*)